# Why the flag bit LOAD_TLB_AS_64BIT of LoadTypeLibEx does not take effect

Tags: windows, com, ole

sample code

```
ITypeLib* pp;
TLIBATTR* a;
//C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSPPT.OLB
LoadTypeLibEx(_T("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office15\\MSPPT.OLB"), (REGKIND)(REGKIND_NONE| LOAD_TLB_AS_64BIT), &pp);
pp->GetLibAttr(&a);
```

Check that the value of a->syskind is always equal to 1（means SYS_WIN32）.

```
enum tagSYSKIND
{
    SYS_WIN16   = 0,
    SYS_WIN32   = ( SYS_WIN16 + 1 ) ,
    SYS_MAC = ( SYS_WIN32 + 1 ) ,
    SYS_WIN64   = ( SYS_MAC + 1 ) 
}   SYSKIND;
```

Whether the calling method is wrong, why the flag bit LOAD_TLB_AS_64BIT does not take effect.

The expected value is SYS_WIN64

Comment: What error code does LoadTypeLibEx return? Do you build this code with mingw or Visual Studio?

Comment: LoadTypeLibEx is called successful and return S_OK，code is builded with Visual Studio 2013